# .NET 4.x Автоматическое удаление данных из таблицы EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

В EntityFramework есть две сущности:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
}

public class Chapter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Period { get; set; }
}
```

При добавлении в коллекцию `Chapters` объектов `Chapter` они автоматически добавляются в соответствующую таблицу в БД. При удалении в записях удаляется только ссылка на `Book`.

Как сделать так, чтобы при удалении объектов из `Chapters` записи о них удалялись из соответствующей таблицы в БД?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте `BookId` и `Book` в `Chapter`

```
public class Chapter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Period { get; set; }

    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

и сделайте его частью ключа:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Chapter>().Property(c => c.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
modelBuilder.Entity<Chapter>().HasKey(c => new { c.Id, c.BookId });
```

тогда при занулении Chapters или при вызове Chapters.Remove соответствующие Chapters будут удалены.

Полный пример:

```
public class Model1 : DbContext
{
    public Model1()
        : base("name=Model1")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Chapter>().Property(c => c.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Chapter>().HasKey(c => new { c.Id, c.BookId });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
}

public class Chapter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Period { get; set; }

    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new Model1())
        {
            var book = new Book { Chapters = new List<Chapter> { new Chapter() } };
            context.Books.Add(book);
            context.SaveChanges();

            book.Chapters.Add(new Chapter());
            book.Chapters.Add(new Chapter());

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var context = new Model1())
        {
            var book = context.Books.Include("Chapters").First();

            book.Chapters.Add(new Chapter());
            book.Chapters.Add(new Chapter());

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        using (var context = new Model1())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(context.Books.Count()); // 1
            Console.WriteLine(context.Chapters.Count()); // 5
        }

        using (var context = new Model1())
        {
            var b = context.Books.Include("Chapters").First();
            b.Chapters = null;

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var context = new Model1())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(context.Books.Count()); // 1
            Console.WriteLine(context.Chapters.Count()); // 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: мне нужно что бы удаление происходило когда Foreign key Chapters становится в null

Comment: @Serg дописал вариант для зануления

Comment: теперь при попытке добавить записи исключение выскакиевает:Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Chapters'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Chapters'. The duplicate key value is (1, 1).
The statement has been terminated.
Я так понимаю это из-за тоог что в таблице Chapter одно из значений первичного ключа стало автоинкрементироваться(

Comment: @Serg на EF 6 для контекста выше работает `context.Books.Add(new Book { Chapters = new Chapter[] { new Chapter() } });`. Почему не работает на EF4 - не уверен. Если сложно обновляться - то проще руками удалять Chapter-ы при чистке книги.

Comment: можете скинуть тогда полный код что у вас получился ? у меня тоже EF 6

Comment: @Serg ловите полный код

Comment: он работает, но если создать Book с Chapter, сохранить, а после попытаться еще добавить Chapter'ры то будет эксепшен дублирования PK у Chapter. У вас такого нет ?

Comment: @Serg автогенерация отломалась. и заодно ссылка на Book. Исправил.

Comment: все хорошо, единственный вопрос, как можно сделать что бы PK у Book и Chapterзадавался в коде а не автоматически высчитывался в БД ?

Comment: @Serg `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` вместо `Identity` на все подряд. но вообще это стоило бы отдельным вопросом задать